# Linking Combobox Values to a Different Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I'm looking to pull in values into my combobox from a different worksheet.

I've tried looking everywhere and so far I still haven't been able to find a solution.

I came across other StackOverflow posts where someone was asking how to link data values from a different workbook.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    ComboBox1.RowSource = "Brands!A1:A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to give more details. Does Brands Column A contain your data for the combobox?

Comment: yes, it does. i'm looking to populate my userform combobox with data from a different worksheet within the same workbook. The brands are listed in Column A in Worksheet "brands"

Answer (score 0):

It would be advisable for you to find a book or web course on Excel VBA as referencing workbooks, sheets and ranges are explained in more detail there.  You will need to do more to get the entire range of your choice.

```
'In this workbook
ComboBox1.Source = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Brands").Range("A1:A100")

'In another workbook
ComboBox1.Source = Workbooks("WorkBookName").Sheets("Brands").Range("A1:A100")
```